# Book Recommendation on the topic of free will

Tags: free-will

Since I read a few articles on web about free will, I got really curious about work done on "whether  the question whether we have a free will or not?" I also understand proving any of them will be really really hard.

> Can you please recommend books which tackle this question in detail: "Do we have a free will? why or why not."

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you haven't already checked it out, the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (online) presents a range of views in relatively concise, accessible language. The relevant searches for you would include 'Free will', 'Causal determinism', 'Compatibilism', & 'Arguments for Incompatibilism'. Start with 'Free will', which introduces the other concepts.

Comment: @Futilitarian Thanks , I will. Actually, I am a bit busy now a days and will check as soon as I can.